# How to prove that $\frac{a^n}{a^m}$ is equal to $a^{n-m}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How to prove that $\dfrac{a^n}{a^m}$ is equal to $a^{n-m}$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming $n>m>0$.
$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{a^n}{a^m}=\frac{\overbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a\cdots a}^{\large n\text{ times}}}{\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdots a}_{\large m\text{ times}}}=\frac{\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdots  a}}}\overbrace{\cdot a\cdot a\cdots a}^{\large n-m\text{ times}}}{\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdots  a}}}}=a^{n-m}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: @cherry8.8vanilla You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n>m$, then $n$ can be written as $m+r$

$\therefore \Large\frac{a^n}{a^m}=\frac{a^{m+r}}{a^m}=\frac{a^m*a^r}{a^m}=a^r$

but, $n=m+r$  $\Longrightarrow$  $r=n-m$

$\therefore \Large\frac{a^n}{a^m}=a^{n-m}$

Answer (score 1):

depending what you area allowed to use...$\frac{a^n}{a^m} = a^n \cdot \frac{1}{a^m} = a^n \cdot a^{-m}= a^{n-m}$.

EDIT once again, this depends on what you are allowed to use. This is true for $a>0$. Log both sides. On RHS you get $(n-m) \log a$, on LHS $n \log a - m \log a = (n-m) \log a$. Now use the $a \log x  =\log x^a$ property of the log function and exponentiate back.

Comment: I need to show how to get from $\frac{a^n}{a^m}$ or $a^n \cdot \frac{1}{a^m}$ or $a^n \cdot a^{-m}$ this $a^{n-m}$.

Comment: pls see the edit